Social Login on Multi-Tenant Application Built with Laravel 11 and Socialite
I'm building a multi-tenant application with Laravel 11. I wish to offer Social login using Google and LinkedIn. Using Laravel Socialite, it's easy to implement it for the main domain.
I need help figuring out implementing it for hosted subdomains. Here's my overall approach so far:
public function redirect(Request $request, $provider)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'provider' => 'in:google,linkedin-openid'
        ]);

        return Socialite::driver($provider)->with([
            'state' => 'request_domain=' . request()->getHttpHost()
        ])->redirect();
    }

Handling callback is where things get tricky. The main domain is example.com and the subdomain is subdomain.example.com
public function callback(Request $request, $provider)
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();

        $first_name = $user->user['given_name'] ?? null;
        $email = $user->getEmail();

        // Check for the state variable in the incoming callback
        $state = $request->input('state');
        parse_str($state, $domain_data);

        $request_domain = $domain_data['request_domain'];

        $user = Subdomain::where('domain', $request_domain)->where('email', $email)->firstOrFail();

        // Now Auth::login($user); does not work here and the user gets logged-out once I redirect them to the $request_domain.

    }

Can someone help me figure out how to go about this? My wildest attempt so far was to set:
config([
         'app.url' => 'https://'. $request_domain,
         'session.domain' => $request_domain
            ]);

...but that didn't help either.
Would really appreciate if you could show me the way.
